# why the get method not able to use django restframework's request?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have below code snippet

```
class ListAccTokenView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TokenSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        org_id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        entity_id = self.kwargs.get('comp')
        queryset = ErpLinkToken.objects.filter(id=id, comp=comp)
        return queryset


class MeCompInfo(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get_company_info(request):
        get_token = ListAccTokenView.as_view()
        queryset = get_token(Request(Request(request=request)).data
        token = queryset[0]['token'] if queryset else None
        account_token_client = create_merge_client(token)
```

I am getting below error

```
AssertionError at /api/comp
The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.
```

I tried importing  `from django.http import HttpRequest` and converting it to rest_framework instance as seen below, but not helping

```
class MeCompInfo(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get_comp_info(request):
        django_request = HttpRequest()
        django_request.method = request.method
        django_request.GET = request.query_params
        get_token = ListAccTokenView.as_view()
        queryset = get_token(Request(request=django_request)).data
        ac_token = queryset[0]['token'] if queryset else None
        account_token_client = create_merge_client(ac_tok)
        
        
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            api_log(msg="Processing GET request...")

            organization_data = self.get_comp_info(request)
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.

You added `comp=comp`, however, `comp` is not defined in the current scope.

Updated code:

```
entity_id = self.kwargs.get('comp')
queryset = ErpLinkToken.objects.filter(id=id, comp=entity_id)
```